# Looking for information on Trude Schneider, a member of the Bund Deutscher Mädel, Nazi youth league for girls

Tags: germany, 20th-century, records

Trude Schneider was a member of the BDM. My father served in WWII and somehow ended up with her photo album which details her summer in 1940 youth camp, some of that time near Nuremberg. I would love to know who she was/is, what happened to her and who her family was. She may have ended up working for the Ministry of Culture and Propaganda. Goebbels photo is also in the album.

I am a doctoral student and writing my dissertation on this.

Comment: It is not impossible that she is still alive.  You have to be very careful with possible identification:  See, amongst others, this discussion https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2067/2663

Comment: Our privacy policy appears in the [help/on-topic] and I agree with @Chenmunka that there seems to be a chance that Trude could still be alive so please take care as you [edit] your question to provide any additional details.  Any answerers should take similar care.

Comment: A poor hint is that Trude certainly stands for Gertrud. Unfortunately, Schneider is a very common name in Germany and Gertrud was a top 30 first name for girls in Germany the 30s. A second piece of info is that she must have been between 14 and 18 in 1940, this restricts the year of birth to the range 1921-1926.

Comment: Some potential information on a german genealogy site : https://www.myheritage.de/research?s=77761723&formId=master&formMode=1&action=query&exactSearch=0&useTranslation=1&catId=1&qname=Name+fn.Gertrud+ln.Schneider+g.F&qevents-event1=Event+et.birth+ey.1923+me.true+mer.2+epmo.similar&qevents=List

Comment: Thank-you all for your response. I continue to look for her. It appears there was an actress in Germany by the same name about that time but from the photos I have it does not appear to be the same person.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.  In the meantime I'll convert your "answer" to be a comment on your question.

Comment: I am not aware of extensive member lists of mass organizations like BDM or Hitlerjugend. There might never have been a centralized file. I assume records on membership were kept on a lower level (e.g. Gau). A lot of records of all kinds were destroyed during the war. Only a index of nazi party (NSDAP) membership records was not burned (as planned), but discovered by American troops and later transferred to the federal archive (Bundesarchiv). On request, it can be searched by name and birth date. You won‘t get a list of all members with a certain name (no such service, legal restrictions).

Comment: Is there other personal or contextual information (places, people, dates) in the album that might help to progress? As a sidenote, the photo of Goebbels in this is mostly useless. Is it a photo likely taken by Trude?